# Excel vba : If Listbox selected value = 2 then show textbox4 else hide textbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a listbox with values from a sheet called `Database OUtypes`. Values are:

1. Single Split
2. Multi Split
3. City Multi

I want a "MultiSplit"(textbox) that shows when value `2` is selected in listbox and hide when the other values are selected.

How can i do that ?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Unload Me
Menu.Show
End Sub

Private Sub userform_activate()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim cell As Range
With Worksheets("Database Bedrijf")
For Each cell In .Range("B1:B1000" & .cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then Bedrijf.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
End With
With Worksheets("Database Freon")
For Each cell In .Range("B1:B1000" & .cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then Freontype.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
End With
With Worksheets("Database OUtypes")
For Each cell In .Range("B2:B1000" & .cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then OUtypes.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
End With
'''This declares the data type of the variable "LstRw'
Dim LstRw As Long
'''This defines what the variable "LstRw' is to refer to. _
   (The row number of the last used cell in column A.)
LstRw = cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'''This tells the textbox named ID to equal the value of the last used cell in Col.A after adding 1 to it.
ID.caption = cells(LstRw, "A").Value + 1
End Sub


Private Sub Freontypes_Change()

    gwp.Text = Application.VLookup(Freontype.Value, Worksheets("Database Freon").Range("B2:C1000"), 2, False)

End Sub

Private Sub Bedrijf_Change()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim countExit As Integer
Dim CellCombo2 As String
Dim i As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database Klant")
RowMax = wsh.cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'find last row of sheet in column A

Klant.Clear
'clear all value of comboBox2

With Klant
    For i = 2 To RowMax
        If wsh.cells(i, "B").Value = Bedrijf.Text Then
        'Just show value of mapping with column A
        .AddItem wsh.cells(i, "C").Value
        Else
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
Private Sub Freoninhoud_Change()
    If Freoninhoud.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Vul iets in"
        Exit Sub
    Else
     Co2.Text = CDbl(Replace(Me.Freoninhoud.Text, ".", ",")) * gwp.Text
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    Status.AddItem "Goed"
    Status.AddItem "Slecht"
    Status.AddItem "Defect"

Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim countExit As Integer
Dim CellCombo1 As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database Bedrijf")
RowMax = wsh.cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'find last row of sheet in column A

Bedrijf.Clear
'clear all value of comboBox1

With Bedrijf

    For i = 2 To RowMax
    'Run each row of column A

    countExit = 0
    CellCombo1 = wsh.cells(i, "B").Value

            For j = i To 2 Step -1
            'just show value not duplicate

            If CellCombo1 = wsh.cells(j, "A").Value Then
            countExit = countExit + 1
            End If
            Next j
        If countExit = 0 Then

        ElseIf countExit > 1 Then
            Else
            .AddItem CellCombo1
            End If
    Next i

End With
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Database OU")
    lRow = ws.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With ws
        .cells(lRow, 1).Value = ID.caption
        .cells(lRow, 2).Value = Bedrijf.Value
        .cells(lRow, 3).Value = Klant.Value
        .cells(lRow, 4).Value = Ruimte.Value
        .cells(lRow, 5).Value = Merk.Value
        .cells(lRow, 6).Value = Types.Value
        .cells(lRow, 7).Value = Multisplit.Value
        .cells(lRow, 8).Value = Model.Value
        .cells(lRow, 9).Value = Serienummer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 10).Value = Bouwjaar.Value
        .cells(lRow, 11).Value = Afvoer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 12).Value = Freontype.Value
        .cells(lRow, 13).Value = Freoninhoud.Value
        .cells(lRow, 14).Value = Co2.Text
        .cells(lRow, 15).Value = Installatienummer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 16).Value = Adres.Value
        .cells(lRow, 17).Value = Status.Value
    End With
    Unload Me
    Menu.Show
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Database OU")
    lRow = ws.cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With ws
        .cells(lRow, 1).Value = ID.caption
        .cells(lRow, 2).Value = Bedrijf.Value
        .cells(lRow, 3).Value = Klant.Value
        .cells(lRow, 4).Value = Ruimte.Value
        .cells(lRow, 5).Value = Merk.Value
        .cells(lRow, 6).Value = Types.Value
        .cells(lRow, 7).Value = Multisplit.Value
        .cells(lRow, 8).Value = Model.Value
        .cells(lRow, 9).Value = Serienummer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 10).Value = Bouwjaar.Value
        .cells(lRow, 11).Value = Afvoer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 12).Value = Freontype.Value
        .cells(lRow, 13).Value = Freoninhoud.Value
        .cells(lRow, 14).Value = Co2.Text
        .cells(lRow, 15).Value = Installatienummer.Value
        .cells(lRow, 16).Value = Adres.Value
        .cells(lRow, 17).Value = Status.Value
    End With
    Unload Me
    Outoevoegen.Show
End Sub


Private Sub Userform_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, closemode As Integer)
If closemode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    MsgBox "Sorry gebruik de Sluiten knop"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**

Comment: sorry totally forgot the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
Private Sub OUtypes_Change()
If OUtypes = "Multi Split" Then
Label18.Visible = True
Multisplit.Visible = True
Else
Label18.Visible = False
Multisplit.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Edit: This can be consolidated to be a bit more legible, by using booleans:

```
Private Sub OUtypes_Change()

    visible = (OUtypes = "Multi Split") ' Boolean expression
    Label18.Visible = visible
    Multisplit.Visible = visible

End Sub
```

Comment: I suggest a revision to your answer, to make the code a bit more legible and to take advantage of boolean expressions :)